# Combining date filter using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is it possible to merge two different dates to get the mean value of an image?

I am trying the following code, but at the end I don't get any result.

```
var clipToC1 = function(image){
  return image.clip(geometry)};


var AOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
                  .select('Optical_Depth_055')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01').merge('2019-11-01', '2020-01-01')
                  .map(clipToC1);
                  

var viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 350,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(AOD.mean(), viz, 'Optical Depth 055');


  
 Export.image.toDrive({
   image:AOD.mean(), 
   folder: "Google EE results",
   description: 'jannovdez',
   scale: 1000,
   region:geometry 
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine filters using `ee.Filter.or()`:

```
  collection
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(
      ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'),
      ee.Filter.date('2019-11-01', '2020-01-01')
    ))
```

You have another issue with your script. You're mapping over the collection and clipping each image to a geometry. That's very inefficient. Instead you want to filter the collection by the geometry and clip your final composite.

```
var geometry = Map.getBounds(true)

var AOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
  .select('Optical_Depth_055')
  .filter(ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'),
    ee.Filter.date('2019-11-01', '2020-01-01')
  ))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  
var composite = AOD.mean().clip(geometry)

var viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 350,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
}

Map.addLayer(composite, viz, 'Optical Depth 055')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e105d4ce63e7483e4d81b74985034316